# Voice call not supported and mic record one side in call recording in my android application. I have tested all alternate solution.

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

I am using lenovo K6 power modelno.- Lenovo K33a42.
   Voice call create error on MediaRecorded initialize.
   Below code record one side call please provide me right solution. thanks in 
   adanced.

```
MediaRecorder  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();               
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: Show your Logcat error

Comment: I don't have a logcat error . Error generate on created audio file.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: audio file create on call recording but voice recorded only from my side not other side

Comment: @AnilKumar you can store file in chacheDir when recording after the stop recording copy it and paste your folder